# sparkR hangs in Rstudio

Tags: sparkr

I followed that guidance and installed the spark-1.6.1 and hadoop, but when I run it, it hangs here. (I had to reboot the machines, before it complains JVM doesn't start in 10 seconds)

> sc <- sparkR.init(master = "local")
>   Launching java with spark-submit command C:/spark-1.6.1/bin/spark-submit.cmd   "--packages" "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0" "sparkr-shell" C:\Users\i50194\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUnK05t\backend_portff47fcb7e27

Comment: Hope this problem is with reference to windows environment, and this happens when there doesn't exist enough RAM (memory) for Java/JVM. Make sure to close other ones using heavy RAM and just re-run the same, it will work.